# Should I accept my supervisor's tasks?

Tags: supervision, delegation

I work in a small data entry company with 10 employees. My responsibility is to check the files completed by the 10 employees. I do it with in-house software and mostly with Microsoft Excel. My supervisor's tasks are below:

1. Mail check
2. File download
3. Assign tasks to team
4. Team handling
5. Uploading files and sending delivery mails to the client
6. Build in-house software with VB.Net for the team when necessary. (But he works only 2 to 3 days in a month on this.)

Since we started working from home and I have 12 years experience in Microsoft Excel (where no other employees, even the supervisor, have experience in it other than .NET), he delegated the tasks 2, 3 & 5 to me. I am unsure whether the MD knows this. I have seen him (the supervisor) in the office (Pre-COVID crisis), he comes to office at 11 AM and tell the team to inform the MD that he (the supervisor) already arrived at 9 AM. So I see his (the supervisor) tasks delegation to me as merely him not wanting to work.

I don't know if my view is correct or this delegation is just the supervisor thing. Should I accept my supervisor's tasks based on the above situation?

Comment: 3 (and I suppose 4), are the concerning one for me, because he is imposing a degree of authority into you where that me improper. If you are doing part of their role, you should speak with whoever decides your salary, and ask them for a bump.

Comment: What does MD mean in this context?

Comment: @BSMP I assumed Managing Director

Comment: @BSMP: The company's owner is in MD (Managing Director) position

Comment: @ljden: Correct

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is a bit unclear - the title and the body ask different questions ("Should I accept tasks?" vs. "Is my view correct?"). Also asking "what should I do" is [generally off-topic](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/what-questions-are-off-topic-here) - we can explain options, but you must decide what you want. Please edit to clarify what you do not understand, or what your goal is.

Comment: @sleske: I've edited the question

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - MD makes sure the supervisor works.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - If I refuse to perform the supervisor's tasks then my supervisor will direct me to do some tasks of team members also which will make my working hours long and he may report me like I am inefficient if my checking process takes time.

Comment: You have no idea how much he works on task 6. Task 6 is 90% of his job, you are assisting with a tiny fraction of his job, but you think you are doing more like 75% of it. You are dead wrong bud.

Comment: @Issel: Sorry bud: We all have seen him in office where he mostly talks in phone with his friends. We don't complain because he is in supervisor role. I know when he works in task 6 because I am in CC in mail notification from client and he does the job in the desk next by me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Your comment is correct. Thank you for your inputs which cleared my dilemma. Now I decided to change the boat instead rock it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know, for certain, if the supervisors job is complete tasks 1-6, or ensure tasks 1-6 are completed? If you do, you have your answer, if not then it is very hard to know for sure and you should avoid making accusations at work. Also, is this long term or short term?

If you are happy to do the additional work, you could ask your supervisor for a raise to reflect the extra responsibility you have taken on.
If this would be fruitless with the supervisor, and you are willing to rock the boat, you could go to the MD and make this request (without any accusations of the supervisor offloading). This means you can draw your MD's attention to your supervisor offloading tasks without being seen as calling out the supervisor. Directly complaining can come off as immature and may not go down well with management.
For example:

> "Hey MD, I'm really enjoying the extra work  assigned to me. I'm happy to keep doing the work but I would like my salary to reflect the increase in responsibility"

This could also be done over email.

> I have seen him when in office he comes at 11 AM and ask the team to inform the MD that he already arrived at 9 AM

Regardless of whether the delegation is what is expected of him, or him getting away with offloading, requesting you to lie is a huge red flag. Especially if it happens quite often. He may be going through a rough patch, but that doesn't excuse asking you to lie to management.